# Access Facebook page statuses with an app access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

Reading the API docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) I assumed that in order to read a public pages status updates, I would require "any valid access_token or user access_token" (quoting the docs here).

However, if I try to get the status updates for the *public* page, using my app access token, I receive the following response: "A user access token is required to request this resource"

`GET 20531316728/statuses?access_token=myappaccesstoken`

So, my question is if the docs are just plain wrong, I'm doing something wrong or *whatever*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clarification that needs to occur by Facebook [1]. The docs are either outdated or Facebook has changed their mind on handling these updates which is interesting seeing that

```
GET /PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=myappaccesstoken
```

Works (and holds all the statuses). I was told by someone in IRC #facebook that maybe the statuses call is more expensive (Not too bought on this idea).

My current stance is that either

- any valid access_token or user access_token was supposed to imply those excluding app tokens
- Facebook realizes that one can bypass the OAuth Flow by using an app token on pages when Facebook desired some form of authentication.

In the end, these are all assumptions.

I haven't been able to get a clear answer out of any Facebook employee as to whether this is indeed a bug or an intentional removal of this feature.

[1] - http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/480742545315442

Comment: that confirmed what I suspected. Thank you for pointing me to the bug report!